# Git undo a particular commit from the long past

Tags: git

Say these are my commits:

A->B->C->D->E

Now I'm at commit E. But I want to undo the changes I've done between B->C. But I want to keep the changes I made from C->D->E. Perhaps it's a feature I thought it works but it hasn't been thoroughly tested and I want to remove it. So I want a version F which is the same as E but without the changes I made between B->C.

How do I do that? I tried `git diff` to get the difference in B->C but then do `git apply`. It does not apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git revert <commit>` creates a new commit where the content of the specified commit is removed.

Comment: I tried it and it says there is a conflict. Why is that? Within the markers, It has the changes I made between C->D, and D->E. I do not think it should have a conflict on my test project when the change was insertion of a single line. It should just remove that line?

Comment: Oh you're correct. I tried the edits which are further apart and it works.

Comment: I've always thought it reverts all the way back and this was mainly my pain point in trying out git, thanks a bunch.